# Display a data frame table using a filter input to filter rows

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I would like to display a drop down selector and underneath a data frame displayed as a table and filtered on the drop down selection.

Example code:

```
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

# example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'letters': ['A', 'B', 'C']})

# App layout
app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='demo-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'A', 'value': 1},
            {'label': 'B', 'value': 2},
            {'label': 'C', 'value': 3}
        ],
        value=1
    ),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container'),

    # want this df to print out underneath the filter
    dash_table.DataTable(id='df')
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('demo-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return df[df['letters']=='what do I put here to print out the filtered df?']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I'm struggling in two areas related to my goal:

1. Is the gist of line `dash_table.DataTable(id='df')` correct if I want to display a dataframe here? I tried making it static to just show anything but failed.
2. The line `return df[df['letters']=='what do I put here to print out the filtered df?']` hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to do?

Using this example, how can I display a drop down menu and a table where the table is filtered based on the drop down selection?

When I try the above block I get error:

> dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback for `<Output` dd-output-container.children`>` returned a value having type
> `DataFrame` which is not JSON serializable.
>
> The value in question is either the only value returned, or is in the
> top level of the returned list,
>
> and has string representation `Empty DataFrame Columns: [numbers, letters] Index: []`
>
> In general, Dash properties can only be dash components, strings,
> dictionaries, numbers, None, or lists of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of the drop-down is an integer, so it will be the 'number' column of the data frame. Also, the table in Dash is in dict format, so it needs to be converted.

```
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

# example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'letters': ['A', 'B', 'C']})

# App layout
app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='demo-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'A', 'value': 1},
            {'label': 'B', 'value': 2},
            {'label': 'C', 'value': 3}
        ],
        value=1
    ),
    dash_table.DataTable(id='dd-output-container',
                         data=df.to_dict('records'),
                         columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns.values]) #  
])
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('dd-output-container', 'data'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('demo-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    dfs = df.loc[df['numbers'] == value]
    return dfs.to_dict('records') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]